# How do I list all fields of an object in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, class, introspection, objective-c-runtime

If I have a class, how can I list all its instance variable names?

eg:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    int myInt;
    NSString* myString;
    NSMutableArray* myArray;
}
```

I would like to get "myInt", "myString", and "myArray". Is there some way to perhaps get an array of names that I can iterate over?

I've tried searching the Objective-C documentation but couldn't find anything (and I'm not sure what this is called either).

Comment: Are you working from source code (in which case you need an Objective-C parser) or during runtime (in which case you can use the Objective-C runtime API)?

Comment: Source code, ie. the variables will not change during runtime and are all defined in the source code. I'm trying to write a general function to write out to a plist. I know I can use NSDictionary to do that but I'd like to avoid manually adding code all over the place when I add a new class variable, hence the question.

Comment: It sounds then like you actually mean at run time.

Comment: Yes you are right, runtime it is. I found this post http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2008/Aug/msg00176.html that "Firstly, ivars are designed for the object's internal usage." and seems to suggest that using ivars is not a good practice. Are there any pitfalls that I should be aware of? Is using this code going to make something break somewhere else? This is code for an iPhone program if that makes any difference.

Comment: I assume you want to restore the object after you save it to file? If so this is probably not going to work. Just restoring the internal state of an object isn't always enough, there's connections to other objects, notifications, timers, KVOs, delegates, etc. What you want to do is implement the NSCoding protocol in your objects. It's the correct way to archive/restore Cocoa/iOS objects to a file.

Comment: Of course, if you don't want to restore, then ignore my comment. :-D

Comment: For iteration through list of variables of NSManagedObject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301226/how-to-list-variables-for-nsmanagedobject/28302500#28302500

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use the Objective-C runtime API to retrieve the instance variable names:

```
unsigned int varCount;

Ivar *vars = class_copyIvarList([MyClass class], &varCount);

for (int i = 0; i < varCount; i++) {
    Ivar var = vars[i];

    const char* name = ivar_getName(var);
    const char* typeEncoding = ivar_getTypeEncoding(var);

    // do what you wish with the name and type here
}

free(vars);
```

Comment: You'll need this too:  #import <objc/runtime.h>

Answer (score 6):

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>


NSUInteger count;
Ivar *vars = class_copyIvarList([self class], &count);
for (NSUInteger i=0; i<count; i++) {
    Ivar var = vars[i];
    NSLog(@"%s %s", ivar_getName(var), ivar_getTypeEncoding(var));
}
free(vars);
```

Comment: You need to add free(vars); like @JHH above or you have a memory issue

Answer (score 0):

Consider [`gen_bridge_metadata`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/gen_bridge_metadata.1.html), which is intended for a completely different purpose, but can produce XML files from Objective-C header files.