# Outputting iVars from description method?

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables

I am pretty sure I am just missing the point here and getting confused. Can anyone tell me how I might write a simple description for an object that will print out the value of its instance variables to the console.

Also: is there anyway to present the information as a block (i.e. if you had 10 iVars its going to be a pain getting them all to return one by one)

```
@interface CelestialBody : NSObject {
    NSString *bodyName;
    int bodyMass;
}

- (NSString *)description { 
    return (@"Name: %@ Mass: %d", bodyName, bodyMass);
}
```

cheers -gary-

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
- (NSString*)description
{
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@\nMass: %d\nFoo: %@",
     bodyName, bodyMass, foo];
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I was forgetting that I needed to format the string using NSString. Much appreciated ...

Comment: @quinn: please don't arbitrarily edit my posts. If I have a spelling mistake or something and you're desperate to fix it, feel free, but don't arbitrarily reformat my code snippets into your favorite style. It doesn't add any value.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213901/how-do-i-list-all-instance-variables-of-a-class-in-objective-c). The code is reproduced below:

```
unsigned int varCount;

Ivar *vars = class_copyIvarList([MyClass class], &varCount);

for (int i = 0; i < varCount; i++) {
    Ivar var = vars[i];

    const char* name = ivar_getName(var);
    const char* typeEncoding = ivar_getTypeEncoding(var);

    // do what you wish with the name and type here
}

free(vars);
```

Comment: This is useful in a generic sense, but Jason's answer addresses the problem the asker had with using a format string correctly.

Comment: If you have the name of the ivar then using `valueForKey:` to get the value of the ivar through KVC removes the burden to check the type for you, everything is then an object.

Answer (score 1):

As Jason wrote you should use stringWithFormat: to format strings with printf like syntax.

```
-(NSString*)description;
{
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@ Mass: %d", bodyName, bodyMass];
}
```

To avoid writing this over and over again for many classes you could add a category on NSObject that allows you to inspect instance variables easily. This will be bad performance, but works for debugging purposes.

```
@implementation NSObject (IvarDictionary)

-(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithIvars;
{
  NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  unsigned int ivarCount;
  Ivar* ivars = class_copyIvarList([self class], &ivarCount);
  for (int i = 0; i < ivarCount; i++) {
    NSString* name = [NSString stringWithCString:ivar_getName(ivars[i])
                                        encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    id value = [self valueForKey:name];
    if (value == nil) {
      value = [NSNull null];
    }
    [dict setObject:value forKey:name];
  }
  free(vars);
  return [[dict copy] autorelease]; 
}
@end
```

With this in place implementing description is also a piece of cake:

```
-(NSString*)description;
{
  return [[self dictionaryWithIvars] description];
}
```

Do not add this `description` as a category on NSObject, or you might end up with infinite recursions.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a bad idea what you had there, it's almost achievable too.

```
// choose a short name for the macro
#define _f(x,...) [NSString stringWithFormat:x,__VA_ARGS__]

...

- (NSString *) description
{
    return _f(@"Name: %@ Mass: %d", bodyName, bodyMass);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I always wondered how I could shorten that overly verbose stringWithFormat idiom, but I didn't know how to do var args in macros. Now I do :)

Comment: As a side note, you might consider using `##__VA_ARGS__` for more generic variadic argument treatment within macros; otherwise you'll probably get a compiler error for something like `return _f(@"Name is foo");`, where you're providing no variadic argument list in the invocation.

Comment: @fullofsquirrels: but why would you use `_f(@"str")` when you should just use `@"str"`?

Comment: @dreamlax, in this single case, you're right, you probably wouldn't.  I'm thinking of the case of a more general purpose logging system/API, where you just want to throw a random set of arguments at a single method and have it handle things appropriately, rather than having to create a different macro just to handle that special case.