# debug: Obtain a list of all instance variables of an object (unknown type)

Tags: objective-c, debugging, gdb, lldb

Is there any method to obtain (via debug) a list of all instance variables of an unknown object in Objective-c?

I use lldb for debug, but I admit that I don't know it very well.

Obviously I can't look at the header of this unknown object.

I need to do it at debug time, but if it's not possible I can use an alternative at runtime.

I've found this post: [How do I list all fields of an object in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213901/how-do-i-list-all-instance-variables-of-a-class-in-objective-c) but, as I understand, I need to have a known Class (I need the headers of the object)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Exploiting the code of the accepted answer of the question that you linked, the only thing that you need to do is to wrap it into a convenient method, so that you could call it at any time during debug. At your place I would write a category extending *NSObject*, adding a method that returns a *NSDictionary* with all the ivars; Here is an example:

```
- (NSDictionary*) ivars
{
    NSMutableDictionary* ivarsDict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
    unsigned int count;
    Ivar* ivars=class_copyIvarList([self class], &count);
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        Ivar ivar= ivars[i];
        const char* name = ivar_getName(ivar);
        const char* typeEncoding = ivar_getTypeEncoding(ivar);
        [ivarsDict setObject: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",typeEncoding] forKey: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",name]];
    }
    free(ivars);
    return ivarsDict;
}
```

Then given that object of which you don't know the type, if it directly or indirectly inherits from *NSObject* you just need to print the dictionary returned from this method:

```
(lldb) po [someObject ivars]
```

Credits: [How do I list all fields of an object in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213901/how-do-i-list-all-instance-variables-of-a-class-in-objective-c/1213979#1213979)

**PS:** You need to import *objc/runtime.h* .

Comment: Yeah, it's very good! Additional information: If you want to print informations about unknown object ivars (let's say: private Apple objects), you must create a fake header for that class, including the ivars. Otherwise, lldb would give you an error. Thank you very much!

Comment: Anyone got something handy for Swift?

Answer (score 14):

Since you are using lldb, you may want to try

```
_ivarDescription
_propertyDescription
_methodDescription
_shortMethodDescription
```

You can use them with `po` when you hit a breakpoint

```
po [yourObject _ivarDescription]
```

Comment: That is a *spectacular* tip. Am debugging a crash in CFNetwork involving undocumented iOS types and invoking `po [$x0 _ivarDescription]` when lldb is paused at the start of an instance method is proving extremely helpful.