# How to parse an object to obtain keys values (attribute/value) in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

I want to get the values of all attributes of an object in Objective-C.
For example I have an instance of my class `Client`,  named `Client1`.
I would like to have a method which get this object as a parameter and returns the attributes and values. (`name = 'nameC1'`, `age = 21`, ...)

Comment: Do you know the attributes of it up front or are you asking how to enumerate the properties of a class?

Comment: Hi , 
the function should work for any object... ( enumerate all attribut + their values )

Comment: Any particular object class? Or simply any objects?

Comment: Any particular object class ... It's possible to do this ?

Comment: What does that have to do with `gnustep`? Is it important?

Comment: I encountered a similar question few time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304483/debug-obtain-a-list-of-all-instance-variables-of-an-object-unknown-type/16305101

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri does that handle primitive types such as ints?

Comment: @powerj1984 Yes, it does. For example the type of an int will appear as @"i" in the dictionary. In this case an extra job is needed to find the values of every ivar, by iterating all the keys and call *valueForKey:* on the object of which you want to analyze the ivars.

Comment: @user2421041 You really don't want to go down this path.  It'll only lead to pain.   Your data model should be well defined, with a known and controlled set of properties and relationships.  Trying to automate persistence and/or visualization through deep runtime introspection just leads to a fragile and unmaintainable codebase.

Answer (score 2):

This question was a bit different, but I think the answer is the same as the answer to your question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8380836/104527

```
// PropertyUtil.h
#import 

@interface PropertyUtil : NSObject

+ (NSDictionary *)classPropsFor:(Class)klass;

@end


// PropertyUtil.m
#import "PropertyUtil.h"
#import "objc/runtime.h"

@implementation PropertyUtil

static const char * getPropertyType(objc_property_t property) {
    const char *attributes = property_getAttributes(property);
    printf("attributes=%s\n", attributes);
    char buffer[1 + strlen(attributes)];
    strcpy(buffer, attributes);
    char *state = buffer, *attribute;
    while ((attribute = strsep(&state, ",")) != NULL) {
        if (attribute[0] == 'T' && attribute[1] != '@') {
            // it's a C primitive type:
            /* 
                if you want a list of what will be returned for these primitives, search online for
                "objective-c" "Property Attribute Description Examples"
                apple docs list plenty of examples of what you get for int "i", long "l", unsigned "I", struct, etc.            
            */
            return (const char *)[[NSData dataWithBytes:(attribute + 1) length:strlen(attribute) - 1] bytes];
        }        
        else if (attribute[0] == 'T' && attribute[1] == '@' && strlen(attribute) == 2) {
            // it's an ObjC id type:
            return "id";
        }
        else if (attribute[0] == 'T' && attribute[1] == '@') {
            // it's another ObjC object type:
            return (const char *)[[NSData dataWithBytes:(attribute + 3) length:strlen(attribute) - 4] bytes];
        }
    }
    return "";
}


+ (NSDictionary *)classPropsFor:(Class)klass
{    
    if (klass == NULL) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *results = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];

    unsigned int outCount, i;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(klass, &outCount);
    for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        const char *propName = property_getName(property);
        if(propName) {
            const char *propType = getPropertyType(property);
            NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:propName];
            NSString *propertyType = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:propType];
            [results setObject:propertyType forKey:propertyName];
        }
    }
    free(properties);

    // returning a copy here to make sure the dictionary is immutable
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:results];
}
@end
```

To use import PropertyUtil.h and do something like:

```
NSDictionary props = [PropertyUtil classPropsFor:[YourClass class]];
```

Comment: Answers the concrete question.  However, don't use this kind of code.  While such automated, deep introspection, seems like a time saver, it will lead to a fragile, unmaintainable, code base.

Comment: I have to agree completely