# How to list variables for NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data, runtime, nsmanagedobject

I needs to list variables for NSManagedObject, I know there is a way to do it using "class_copyIvarList" as given in [How do I list all fields of an object in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213901/how-do-i-list-all-fields-of-an-object-in-objective-c)

but "class_copyIvarList" isn't working on "NSManagedObject".

here is piece of code Im using, which is working perfectly fine for "NSObject" but not for "NSManagedObject":

```
  unsigned int outCount;
  Ivar *vars = class_copyIvarList([self class], &outCount);
  for (int i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
    Ivar var = vars[i];
    unsigned int idCount;

    NSLog(@"%s %s", ivar_getName(var), ivar_getTypeEncoding(var));

  }
  free(vars);
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Would properties work for you as well as ivars?

Comment: if you are asking class_copyIvarList returning properties for NSObject then yes it is returning but I need it working for NSManagedObject

Comment: Using `class_copyPropertyList` gets you the properties of a class (even subclass of `NSManagedObject`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing here, but with managed objects it's usually more typical to use Core Data's own introspection rather than ask the Objective-C runtime. In a method on a managed object subclass, you'd use `[[self entity] propertiesByName]` to get a list of all attributes and relationships defined by the entity type. You could replace that method with `attributesByName` or `relationshipsByName` depending on what you need. The objects you get back can be further queried, for example to find out the type of a property or the target entity of a relationship.